# Three phase motor current verification

Tags: current-measurement, brushless-dc-motor, three-phase

I want to verify that the quadrature current through a permanent magnet synchronous motor (PMSM) is actually the same amount as I commanded the field-oriented control (FOC) motor controller to push it through.

I have only one current clamp so I can only measure one phase at a time. Is the actual motor current just 3 times the RMS current through one phase?

Answer (score 1):

Essencially yes.

To determine the power flowing into or out of a 3phase system you can make use of

1. 1wattmeter method
2. 2wattmeter method
3. 3wattmeter method

In this instance you could take advantage of this and assume the 3 currents are the same (bar phaseshift) to derive the currents of the 3phase system.

HOWEVER... you are interested in Iq which means you really need to know all 3 currents and equally the present angular position to then apply park&clark transformations correctly.

Any slight disturbance in the other 2 current waveforms would influence the actual Iq used by your FOC, something you would not be able to see.

For a CRUDE 1st approximation, yes you could take the one and phaseshift it to produce the other 2 waveforms

Comment: When you say 1 watt method, do you mean wattmeter?

Comment: I assume that your controller measures the current in at least 2 phases.  If you want to verify the accuracy of your controller's Iq field orientation it would be hard to do it with something that is much less accurate (1 meter, no angular information) than what the controller is doing.

Comment: @Andyaka, yes. I hit submit too early. edited

Comment: @JohnD, I only need a ball park figure to make sure it's not off by a factor of 2. I just discovered this week someone in the past must have forgotten to inform the software guys the conversion factor from ADC counts to amps and the other way around had changed (by a factor two...).

Comment: If you want to see if they are off by a factor of two there is no need to derive the other two phases let alone do the DQ transformations. The peak DC quantity for Iq will essentially equal the peak of the 3 phase currents.  Just measure the abc domain currents & note the peak of any of them and it is near enough to Iq for most quick checks.  back-transforming is only of benefit if for instance you see some form of lower-freq AM going on or if there is an imbalance in the 3phases